# Android emulator not tack right layout

Tags: android, android-emulator

I created a 3 layout HDPI, MDPI, IDPI. And in the system android emulator i created 3 emulators
but same time it tack the right one,

I tested it into canvas HD phone but, in the phone it take the normal layout only ,
Why does the phone not take a HDPI layout?

in my Android Manifest

```
 <supports-screens
    android:anyDensity="true"
    android:smallScreens="true"
    android:largeScreens="true"
    android:normalScreens="true"
 />
```

Comment: can you show me your project structure? see my answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15090752/how-to-include-10-and-7-layouts-properly/15091224#15091224

Comment: but canvas HD (480*800) screen density ,it means it is HDIP .but normal screen density is (320*480) .but why it tack the normal screen .......

Comment: you are going in wrong track. if you declare `layout` directory, it supports all the `normal` screen. It doesn't matter whether it is `small`,`medium`,`high` or `extra high` density. Please read Developer Android site multiple screen support carefully.

Answer (score 3):

Can you try putting this in your AndroidManifest.xml

```
    <compatible-screens>

    <!-- all small size screens -->
    <screen
        android:screenDensity="ldpi"
        android:screenSize="small" />
    <screen
        android:screenDensity="mdpi"
        android:screenSize="small" />
    <screen
        android:screenDensity="hdpi"
        android:screenSize="small" />
    <screen
        android:screenDensity="xhdpi"
        android:screenSize="small" />
    <!-- all normal size screens -->
    <screen
        android:screenDensity="ldpi"
        android:screenSize="normal" />
    <screen
        android:screenDensity="mdpi"
        android:screenSize="normal" />
    <screen
        android:screenDensity="hdpi"
        android:screenSize="normal" />
    <screen
        android:screenDensity="xhdpi"
        android:screenSize="normal" />
</compatible-screens>
```

Support Screeens

```
    <supports-screens
    android:anyDensity="true"
    android:largeScreens="true"
    android:normalScreens="true"
    android:resizeable="true"
    android:smallScreens="true" >
</supports-screens>
```