# Which screen size qualifiers should I choose?

Tags: android, orientation, adt, screen-size, mobile-devices

I'm currently developing an application that should support different screen size (phones and tablets) as well as different screen orientations. Should I use smallest width (layout-sw320dp for phones and so on) and port/land (layout-sw320dp-land ...) qualifiers to determine how many views I can fit on the screen or is there any better way to go about it?

I could also use small, normal, large, xlarge qualifiers but I read 
(here http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html) 
that those were deprecated with API level 13, which brings me to my next question.

Does API level 8, which is my minimum API level, support smallest width qualifiers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it won't support smallest width qualifiers. (Supported only in Android 3.2+)
You'll have to use the "old school" way of supporting multiple devices.

On how to do this you can follow this answer:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/15113877