# including android res files for 8"

Tags: android, layout

how to include layout for 8"

I have already used layouts for 7" and 10". but 8" is creating confusion for me.

- 7" has 800*1280  large
- 8" has 1024*768
- 10" has  1280*768.  xlarge

Please guide me through the layout, drawable, and dimens file. If possible please provide a general way so that workload can be lessened.

Comment: see this http://developer.android.com/training/basics/supporting-devices/index.html

Comment: see this as well http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Comment: refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15090752/how-to-include-10-and-7-layouts-properly

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Do I need 14 different layouts to support all Android devices?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5558534/do-i-need-14-different-layouts-to-support-all-android-devices)

Comment: Thank you guys for replying

Comment: hello.. All links were working fine with 7" and 10". but none of them was helping me with 8". can anyone please help ,me with 8"?